# Why "service sshd start" command can not return to command prompt?

Tags: linux, service, centos7, systemd, sshd

I'm install a new CentOS7, its sshd service works fine. Then I download the source code of openssh7.5p1, build it and install it to the default directory "/usr/local/sbin/sshd". I want to use it to replace the system's sshd.

1. I modify the file "/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service", change following line:

   `old:
   ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd $OPTIONS
   new:
   ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/sshd $OPTIONS`
2. After that, type command "service sshd start", the command can not return and seems hang up. Looks as follows:

   `[root@localhost ~]# service sshd start
   Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  sshd.service`
3. I press Ctl+C to terminate the command. Then use command "netstat -ntlp" to find that the "sshd" already started, not sure why the "service sshd start" can not return to prompt.

   `[root@localhost ~]# netstat -ntlp
   Active Internet connections (only servers)
   Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address     Foreign Address  State       PID/Program name

   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111       0.0.0.0:*        LISTEN      1/systemd

   tcp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53  0.0.0.0:*        LISTEN      2443/dnsmasq

   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22        0.0.0.0:*        LISTEN      63144/sshd

   tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631     0.0.0.0:*        LISTEN      1043/cupsd

   tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25      0.0.0.0:*        LISTEN      1815/master

   tcp6       0      0 :::111            :::*             LISTEN      1/systemd

   tcp6       0      0 :::22             :::*             LISTEN      63144/sshd

   tcp6       0      0 ::1:631           :::*             LISTEN      1043/cupsd

   tcp6       0      0 ::1:25            :::*             LISTEN      1815/master`
4. I try to start sshd manually, it works fine, the sshd started successfully(no any warning message) and the command return immediately. The command as follows:

   `[root@localhost ~]# /usr/local/sbin/sshd -f /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Any help is appreciated. Let me know if you want to known more information. Thanks.

Comment: What is in the logs? Can you provide the output of `journalctl -u sshd`?

Answer (score 0):

How about tinkering With type in your .service ?
have you tried to set it to idle ?
maybe systemd waits to receive a message from sshd and seems to hang..